# Can I turn off logging in SLF4J SimpleLogger?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I'm using SLF4J SimpleLogger for unit tests.  Due to external factors, it would be challenging to change log providers.

The class under test grabs a logger from the owning framework to record errors.  The problem is that when I test an error condition, I wind up with a big scary error message in the test logs, even though the test passes. I think this is a Bad Thing.

When I used to use Log4J, I could grab the logger for the class under test and change its level to OFF before running the test, then change it back. It looks like SimpleLogger doesn't have an OFF level, so the quietest setting would be ERROR, which of course still logs when `error()` is called.

Is there a better way to do this?  Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you need to turn it off for just one test or for all your tests?

Comment: Just a few tests -- most of the test cases are positive but a few are to verify error handling.  Ideally, if a positive test case goes wrong, I should see errors in the test logs, so I'd like to not *totally* disable logging during test execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-332 and https://www.slf4j.org/news.html SLF4J 1.7.22 added support for OFF level in SimpleLogger.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to the project in question anymore but I'm going to assume that this would have solved it.

Comment: gosh I thought I was at 1.7.21 due to transitive dependencies and thought I was at 1.7.30 and couldn't figure it out for a while :)